# Texture stuck on Black! Unity 5.6

Tags: unity-game-engine

I copied a project over from a different PC which had multiple scenes that needed to be baked.

The problem is in this one scene there are several different objects that textures seen to be stuck on black, even though I've changed the color of them. Some materials that where imported also seemed to be grayed out and I couldn't make any changes to them.

I'm not sure whether this is a baking issue or something to do with the material. I have tried to put the object on a different layer and used a real-time light and it does make it lighter but still nowhere near the color i set it too.

There are some textures/ Objects that are used in different scenes that seem to work fine but in this scene they don't...

None of the settings have been changed and it is the same version of unity on both PC's.

The issue:
[image: Issue]

What it is supposed to look like (from previous version):
[image: What it is supposed to look like]

Comment: Have you tried Assets > Reimport All from the top menu?

Comment: Yes i have, Still no luck. Also Cleared lightmap data and re-baked but still having the same issue.